# I have a short question regarding units of this question

Tags: thermodynamics

A piston-cylinder machine contains 1 kg of air, initially at v = 0.8 m<sup>3</sup>/kg and 290 K. The gas is compressed in a slow frictionless process to a specific volume of v = 0.2 m<sup>3</sup>/kg and a temperature of 580 K, according to the equation **pv<sup>1.5</sup> = 0.75** (where p is in bar and v as shown). Determine the work and the heat transfer.

[image]
The correct answer for the work from the textbook is -167.72 kJ

Does anyone know why my answer is a factor of 100 too small?

Comment: What about temperature?

Comment: You calculate units by actually writing down the units. For instance what units are you using on volume? You haven't tried this. Also, the title is very generic. It would be better to have it better reflect the question.

Comment: Pay attention to Solar Mike's comment, nowhere in your equation has related the volume change with respect to the temperature change. Also, the integration of P*dv and the subsequent numerical evaluation seems incorrect.